# Pegar o ultimo valor de um Array dentro de um Foreach

Tags: php, array, laravel, foreach

Estou fazendo um `foreach` que trás a seguinte base de dados:

```
$notificacoes = Notificacoes::where('user_id', $id)
          ->where('lido', false)
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->get();

$notificacao->load('causa','causa.cliente','causa.cliente.user','causa.mensagem');
return $notificacoes;
```

Na Blade estou execuntado o seguinte `foreach`

```
@foreach($notificacoes as $notificacao)
            @if($notificacao->tipo == 'NOVA MENSAGEM')
            <div class="comment-widgets m-b-20">
                <!-- Comment Row -->
                <div class="d-flex flex-row comment-row">
                    <div class="comment-text w-100">
                        <h5><a href="#">{{$notificacao->causa->cliente->user->nome}}</a> te enviou uma nova mensagem na causa:</h5>
                        <div class="comment-footer">
                        <p class="m-b-5 m-t-10">{{$notificacao->causa->assunto}}</p>
                            <span class="date">{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($notificacao->created_at))}} as {{date('H:i:s', strtotime($notificacao->created_at))}} </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Comment Row -->
            </div>
            @endif
@endforeach
```

Todavia quando chega em `$notificacao->causa->mensagem` eu trago um `array` e preciso apenas da ultima mensagem enviada. Segue a foto do `dump` and `die`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como pegaria qualquer valor dentro do ultimo índice de `array` dentro do `foreach`?

Comment: Algo como a função `end()`?

Comment: Vi algo sobre o end(), todavia não consegui implementar uma vez que dentro do ultima indice iria pegar os dados  "mensagem" e "criated_at". Você teria noção te como proceder?

Comment: Ou como é laravel e não é tão simples quanto poderia ser, talvez seja `$notificacao->causa->mensagem->last()->created_at`

Comment: Devo admitir que não conhecia o last(). Todavia funcionou perfeitamente. Solução rapida e útil

Comment: Você deveria pensar em carregar somente a última mensagem e ai mostrar! o comando citado acima é correto, mas, eu acho que o mais correto é trazer só o que precisa!

Comment: Se você pegar sua coleção é só fazer um count dela - 1 que você vai ter a posição do último array: `$collection[count($collection) - 1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traga apenas da sua base de dados o que precisa, faça um carregamento com filtro e limite da seguinte forma:

```
$notificacao = Notificacoes::where('user_id', $id)
    ->where('lido', false)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

$notificacao->load('causa','causa.cliente','causa.cliente.user');
$notificacao->load(['causa.mensagem' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')
          ->limit(1);
}]);

return $notificacoes;
```

Foi colocado `id` para ordenação do *maior para o menor* e um `limit` **1** para trazer apenas o último registro inserido, mas, pode ser colocado o campo que tem referencia a esse aspecto.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Eloquent: Relationships - Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)</sup>